# Aurelia Validation on Array Property and select tag

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I am using Aurelia framework for my website and have implemented validations as per the example shown in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653206/aurelia-trigger-validation-on-tab-outblur-event/37821945#37821945).

As per the approach shown in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653206/aurelia-trigger-validation-on-tab-outblur-event/37821945#37821945), I am unable to implement validation for some specific property of array and even for select tags.

> **Example For Array Property(input tag):**
>
> **JavaScript**:

```
this.arr=[{Id:1, Name: 'John'}, {Id:2, Name:'Sam'}, {Id:3, Name:'Kim'}];
```

> **HTML:**

```
<div repeat.for="item of arr">
   <input value.bind="item.Name & validate"/>
</div>
```

Now I want to write rule for '*Name*' property of '*arr*'.
I am clueless how I should proceed.

And similar kind of issue I am facing for **select tag**.

> **Example For select tag:**
>
> **JavaScript**:

```
this.arr=[{Id:1, Name: 'John'}, {Id:2, Name:'Sam'}, {Id:3, Name:'Kim'}];
```

> **HTML:**

```
<select value.bind="selectedValue & validate">
     <option repeat.for="item of arr" value.bind="item.Id" model.bind="item.Id">${item.Name}</option>
</select>
```

Any suggestion or example will be great help.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be the dot in the item's property.  I'm experiencing the same problem right now when I use properties like person.firstname, person.lastname, etc.  Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: any update on this Ankur? did you figure out how to fix this?